# Generic Interface w/ Polymorphism to handle Objects

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, abstraction

Previous Post removed; **Updated**:

---

So I have a unique issue, which is possibly fairly common though.  Properties are quite possibly are most commonly used code; as it requires our data to keep a constant value storage.  So I thought how could I implement this; then I thought about how easy Generics can make life.  Unfortunately we can't just use a Property in a Generic without some heavy legwork.  So here was my solution / problem; as I'm not sure it is the best method- That is why I was seeking review from my peers.

Keep in mind the application will be massive; this is a very simple example.

**Abstract:**

Presentation Layer: The interface will have a series of fields; or even data to go across the wire through a web-service to our database.

```
// Interface:
public interface IHolder<T>
{
     void objDetail(List<T> obj);
}
```

So my initial thought was an interface that will allow me to Generically handle each one of my objects.

```
// User Interface:
public class UI : IHolder
{
    void objDetail(List<object> obj)
    {
        // Create an Instance
        List<object> l = new List<object>();
        // Add UI Fields:
        l.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        l.Add(txtFirst.Text);
        l.Add(txtLast.Text);
        // l to our obj        
        obj = l;
        return;
     }
}
```

Now I have an interface; which has been used by our UI to put information in.  Now; this is where the root of my curiosity has been thrown into the mixture.

```
// Create an Object Class
public class Customer : IHolder
{
     // Member Variable:
     private Guid _Id;
     private String _First;
     private String _Last;

     public Guid Id
     { 
           get { return _Id; }
           set { _Id = value; }
     }
     public String First
     {
           get { return _First; }
           set { _First = value; }
     }
     public String Last
     {
           get { return _Last; }
           set { _Last = value; }
     }

     public virtual objDetail(List<Customer> obj)
     {
         // Enumerate through List; and assign to Properties.
     }
}
```

Now this is where I thought it would be cool; if I could use Polymorphism to use the same interface; but Override it to do the method differently. So the Interface utilizes a Generic; with the ability to Morph to our given Object Class.

Now our Object Classes; can move toward our Entity interface which will handle basic Crud Operation.

I know this example isn't the best for my intention; as you really don't need to use Polymorphism.  But, this is the overall idea / goal...

- Interface to Store Presentation Layer UI Field Value
- Implement the Properties to a Desired Class
- Create a Wrapper Around my Class; which can be Polymorphed.
- Morphed to a Generic for Crud Operation

Am I on the right path; is this taboo?  Should I not do this?  My application needs to hold each instance; but I need the flexibility to adapt very quickly without breaking every single instance in the process.  That was how I thought I could solve the issue.  Any thoughts?  Suggestions?  Am I missing a concept here?  Or am I over-thinking? Did I miss the boat and implement my idea completely wrong?  That is where I'm lost...

Comment: Your Customer class doesn't look like it implements ICustomer and your IEntity interface looks more appropriate for a collection than a single entity. Might need to clarify your question and examples.

Comment: Was in a hurry but I agree. Been thinking of how to implement this for most of day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pondering on this scenario a bit, I thought what would provide that flexibility while still ensuring the code is optimized for modification and business.  I'm not sure this is the right solution, but it appears to work.  Not only does it work, it works nicely.  It appears to be fairly robust.

When is this approach useful? Well, when you intend to decouple your User Interface from your Logic.  I'll gradually build each aspect so you can see the entire structure.

```
public interface IObjContainer<T>
{
     void container(List<T> object);
}
```

This particular structure will be important. As it will store all of the desired content into it.

So to start you would create a Form with a series of Fields.

- Personal Information
- Address Information
- Payment Information
- Order Information

So as you can see all of these can be separate Database Tables, but belong to a similar Entity Model you are manipulating.  This is quite common.

So a Segregation Of Concern will start to show slightly, the fields will be manipulated and passed through an Interface.

```
public interface IPersonalInformation
{
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName  { get; set; }
}
```

So essentially the Interface is passing its variable, to the Interface. So you would culminate an interface to handle that entire form or individual interfaces that you wish to call so that they remain reusable.

So now you have a series of Interfaces, or a single once.  But it contains all these variables to use.  So you would now create a class:

```
public class CustomerProperties: IPersonalInformation, IOrderInformation
{
    // Implement each Interface Property
}
```

Now you've created a container that will hold all of your values. What is nifty about this container is you can reuse the same values for another class in your application or choose different ones.  But it will logically separate the User Interface.

So essentially this is acting similar to a Repository.

Now you can take these values and perform the desired logic.  What becomes wonderful now, is after you've performed your logic you pass the object into our Generic List.  Then you simply implement that method in another class for your goal and iterate through your list.

The honesty is it appears to work well and decouple nicely.  I feel that it was a lot of work to do something similar to a normal Repository and Unit Of Work, this answers the question but weather or not it is ideal for your project I would look into Repository, Unit Of Work, Segregation Of Concern, Inversion Of Control, and Dependency Injection.  They may do this same approach cleaner.

---

**Update:**

I thought about it after I wrote this up, I noticed you could actually implement those property values into the Generic List structure bypassing a series of interfaces; but that would introduce consistency issues as you'd  have to be aware of what data is being passed in each time, in order.  It's possible, but may not be ideal.